# Template function VS bigger templates

Tags: angularjs, performance

Lets say you have some component: `<myComponent my-bool="true">` and you want have different template depending on `myBool` attribute.

1st way, just make bigger template:

```
<span ng-if="$ctrl.myBool">...
<div ng-if="$ctrl.myBool">...
```

2nd way, make template function:

```
template : (el, attrs) => attrs.myBool ? 'span.html' : 'div.html'
```

Is there any pros and cons of using 1st or 2nd approach from preformance point of view?
Does any kind of precompile exist in angularjs 1.X? (Cause, in 1st way you can imagine angular pre-compiling template once, when in 2nd it should compile each time)

Comment: Asking about pros and cons is likely to get this question closed as "primarily opinion based", but if you have specific questions (e.g. precompiling), I suggest you focus on those.

Comment: @JLRishe "from preformance point of view" is key here, i am not interested in style/architecture. May be I should ask what is faster...